# Android in windows coaching

Tags: android

Where do I start to learn and work with android?

What are all the things I need to do?

How start work with android, I need proper guide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> where do i start learn and work with
>   android?

The place to start from is developer.android.com. Begin by saying [Hello](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html)

[Here](http://primalpop.wordpress.com/), I have posted the links I found useful for learning Android.

Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

There are a ton of [resources available here](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html) ([Android developer center](http://developer.android.com/) [resources](http://developer.android.com/resources/index.html)) and [the quickstart guide for the sdk](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html#quickstart) is also helpful to getting up and running.

Just poking around [Android developer center](http://developer.android.com/) and some of the other android development related sites should be a great place to start.  Particularly in tutorial sections like the [Hello World tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html).

Answer (score 0):

Read the [Android developer's guide.](http://developer.android.com)